# How to initilaize vector of pairs with NULL (c++)

Tags: c++, null, stdvector

I have a vector of pairs, which is empty at the beginning. I implemented a custom insert and remove method, and I would also like to be able to assign NULL to certain elements, but I can't because it's not a pointer to pair.

If I try to illustrate it more specifically - given a vector V

```
std::vector< std::pair<A,B> > V;
```

neither

```
    V.assign(number,NULL);
```

nor

```
    V[n]=NULL;
```

would work.

I need to do this to check if there already is an element saved in a certain slot. Is there anywork around or should I just create another vector of booleans to save wheter a certian slot is full or not?

NOTE: I know any kind of map would solve it elegantly, but it has to be a vector.

Comment: Maybe you could use boost::optional ?

Comment: I don't think vector is the right container for this use case.

Comment: Yeah I agree with Alex1985.

Comment: V should be a std::vector<std::optional<std::pair<A, B>>>.

Comment: Or maybe a map, like std::map<int, std::pair<A, B> >. You would use map::find to search for elements, it returns map::end if it is not found.

Comment: Yeah, I know hash_map would be ideal for this tipe of task, but the interface requires it to be a vector.


Anyway, optional doesn't seem to be inluded in GNU C++ 4.7.3 
I get fatal error: optional: No such file or directory

Comment: Maybe you should rethink why you want anything to be "null". That sounds like a possibly misguided idea.

Comment: That's class from boost, do you have boost libraries installed, and "boost/optional/optional.hpp" included? Or (for C++11 std::optional) compiling with --std=c++0x ?

Comment: Alex1985: And also part of std, but only since C++14.

KerrekSB: Well, do you have any other idea how to check if a certain element is not set/removed?

Comment: @smihael: You can just randomly initialize things with `NULL`. `NULL` is intended to be used with pointers. Your container elements are not pointers, which means that you will not be able to initialize theme with `NULL` in any meaningful sense of the term. Just forget about `NULL`. If you want to check whether some slot is initialized, you will have to invent something else. `NULL` has no place here whatsoever.

Comment: @smihael If you committed to this design, are there possibly any values of types A,B that you can safely reserve to denote "not a real A" and "not a real B"? If so then the pair comprising those two values could denote "not a real pair<A,B>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to do it I would do something like 
`vector< pair< pair<A,B> ,int > >V` , `V[i].second can be 0 or 1` depending whether the element
pair has to be NULL or not.This if if you want to mark the pair NULL but still keep it for refernece.Otherwise use `map` as Alex1985 said.

Answer (score 2):

I think solution with map would be optimal in your case:

```
std::map<int, std::pair<A, B> > M;
```

Then you can do

```
M.erase(M.find(number))
```

To NULL-ify to the element.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to look at boost::optional

```
boost::optional< std::vector< std::pair<A,B> > > V;
if (V) {
    // V was initialized
} else {
   // wasn't initialized
}
```

documentation examples: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Use shared_ptr as the second type in the pair.

std::vector< std::pair<A,std::shared_ptr<B> > > V;

V.assign(number, std::shared_ptr<B>());

V[n] = std::shared_ptr<B>();

V[n] = std::shared_ptr<B>(new B());

if (V[n].get() == NULL) { /* process empty here */ }

The shared_ptr class was introduced to C++ in TR1, and is part of the C++11 specification. It works well with standard containers because it

Comment: That won't work since the type stored in the vector is `std::pair`. You need to access the member variables of the `pair` accordingly (i.e. `V[n].second = std::shared_ptr<B>();`)